# Did I create my environment variables to be stored $PATH, correctly?

Tags: bash

trying to set up my Django application to work via CURL, not working. The issue is I have to set up my environment variables.

```
SECRET_KEY='stringkeyhere'
DB_ADMIN='admin'
DB_ADMIN_PASS='password'
DB_HOST=111.111.11.111
DB_PORT=2222
DB='database_name'


export SECRET_KEY
export DB_ADMIN
export DB_ADMIN_PASS
export DB_HOST
export DB_PORT
export DB

export PATH=$PATH:$SECRET_KEY/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$DB_PORT/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$DB_ADMIN/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$DB_ADMIN_PASS/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$DB_HOST/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$DB/bin
```

Could I get some verification if I set up my enviroment variables correctly? I want them to be accessible via my `$PATH`. Thank you in advance for your comment.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "accessible via my `$PATH`", but you should *not* be adding them to the `PATH` variable -- that tells the system to treat them as the names of directories it should search for command binaries, which isn't what they are at all.

Comment: How would you recommend I store these environment variables? I want them exported to an `EnviromentFile` that my gunicorn reads. From reading an online guide, I thought the above approach closely resembles the correct form. Seems I was wrong.

Comment: What do you mean "work via CURL"? What do the DB settings have to do with curl?

Comment: You should absolutely not export your password in any way.

Comment: @Der At what level do you want to do the verification? That you typed them correctly? There is a simple solution for comparison. That they work properly? In this case, you have to run a program based on them in bashrc, at the end of the settings, and see its output, if it is as expected, the settings are correct.